# python static method is not getting the latest value of class objects

Tags: python, static-methods

I have a class in python

```
class DeepLearningBot:
    stopwords = ['i',  'am', 'a',
                 'to', 'is', 'do', 'in', 'of']
    labelModelPath = os.path.join(dirName, "..\config\labels_mapping.pkl")
    modelPath = os.path.join(dirName, "models/elmo-model-bilstm2.h5")

    modelBlstm = {}
    modelLabel = {}

    @staticmethod
    def init():
        DeepLearningBot.modelBlstm = tf.keras.models.load_model(DeepLearningBot.modelPath,
                                                                custom_objects={
                                                                    'elmo': hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=False),
                                                                    'tf': tf
                                                                })

        # mapping model of lables and positions
        DeepLearningBot.modelLabel = joblib.load(
            DeepLearningBot.labelModelPath)

    @staticmethod
    def process(query: str) -> Intent:
        intent = DeepLearningBot.__predict(query)
        return intent

    def __predict(query: str) -> Intent:
        with tf.Session() as session:
            K.set_session(session)
            session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
            predictions = DeepLearningBot.modelBlstm.predict([query])

        intent = None

        return intent
```

Now in my **main.py**

I do

```
DeepLearningBot.init()
```

and at my api layer, I use

```
intent = DeepLearningBot.process(query)
```

but it shows the error

```
 predictions = DeepLearningBot.modelBlstm.predict([query])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

it is still accessing the empty `{}` as `modelBlstm` variable.

and if I

```
modelBlstm:Any
```

it says `DeepLearningBot` has no `modelBlstm` variable.

If I debug the code and put a breakpoint inside `init` method it assigns the correct object to `modelBlstm`

Any help?

**UPdate 1**

I tried `@classmethod` over `init` and `process` instead of `@staticmethod` and passed the `cls` param as first param to function.

but still did not work.

Then instead of calling

```
DeepLearningBot.init()
```

from **main.py**, tried calling it from `process()` method itself, then it worked.

But i want `init()` method to be called from outside the same class by other class or **main.py**

Comment: Heads up that if you want to access the *class* in a *method* you very, very, very likely want a ``classmethod`` instead of a ``staticmethod``-accessing-the-class-by-name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, in that case i need to create the object of this class?

Comment: No, a ``classmethod`` can be called on the class, just like a ``staticmethod``. No instance is required. (Though since you must "``init`` the class", just using a regular class design with ``__init__`` and instances would likely not be a bad idea either.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, declared with classmethod, included cls as the first parameter in classmethod functions, stilll the sme issue.. tried updating the objects of cls.modelBlstm, still same issue

Comment: Why is `__query` defined as an instance method if you aren't passing it an instance? For that matter, why is `DeepLearningBot` a class *at all*?

Comment: @chepner u mean __predict right? that is local function that can be declared as static method too, but i am not able to get latest value of modelBlstm that is getting updated using init methid